# How can I check app settings for notifications?

Tags: ios, swift, notifications

This is what I am interested in:

[image]

How to get access to that in code,especially what alert style was set?

Comment: if (&UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString != NULL) {
    NSURL *appSettings = [NSURL URLWithString:UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:appSettings];
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `currentUserNotificationSettings` method:

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().currentUserNotificationSettings()
```

It  will return `UIUserNotificationSettings` object.

Check [UIApplication Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIApplication/currentUserNotificationSettings) for more information.

Comment: What about alert style? In documentation it is not included.

Comment: The `UIUserNotificationType` values are `.None`, `Badge`, `Sound` and `Alert`. I think this is what you are referring to as "style".

Comment: No, notification type is that what user ALLOW to do when notification appear. It may be all of this (.Badge, .Sound, .Alert) or one of them. But this is not the way how it is displayed: banner or alert.

Comment: I think it is something you can't control. AFAIK there is no API to read or set that information.